# write php code in xml file didn't work

Tags: php, xml, output

i tried to write a php code inside an xml file,but the code can't be outputed..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MultimediaGallery>
    <file type="video">
        <thumb>media/videos/thumbs/<?php echo "disney.png"; ?></thumb>
        <source>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irF02LNZLpE</source>
        <description>Youtube Video: Introduction to HTML5</description>
</file>
</MultimediaGallery>
```

result(image of .xml file in a browser)
[image]

Comment: hi mohamed amin, pls edit your question, I don't understand what 1. you tried php-wise, 2. you expect as a desired result, 3. what exactly went wrong and how.

Answer (score 2):

Rename your file .php and change your code like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
?>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <file type="video">
    <thumb>media/videos/thumbs/<?php echo "disney.png"; ?></thumb>
    <source>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irF02LNZLpE</source>
    <description>Youtube Video: Introduction to HTML5</description>
</file>
</MultimediaGallery>
```

Comment: thanks simon,i know this solution,but i want to do this without changing the xml file extension

Comment: to do that you should change your webserver configuration. If you're using Apache you can add this to the config file AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml

Answer (score 0):

PHP in an XML file is not interpreted. However PHP uses a Syntax that can be XML compatible. So a PHP file can be valid XML.

XML has a node type that is called processing instruction. It contains information for the program/application processing the XML. That program can be a web browser, the PHP interpreter or something different. But the program has to know how to interpret the specific processing instruction.

XML processing instruction examples:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
```

The generic syntax is:

```
<?PITarget PIContent?>
```

PHP uses a compatible syntax for its instructions:

```
<?php PHPSource?>
```

That is why a PHP file can be a valid XML file. You can thing of this like English, French, German and other languages all use the same letters, but you still need to know the actual language to understand the words.

So rename the file to `*.php`. This is an information for the web server. It specifies that the file includes PHP source and has to be executed. The output generated by the PHP script is send to the browser. The file extension is not relevant for the browser. The server sends a content type header to the browser. Which content type depends on the configuration of the webserver and if it is a script, on the script.

In a PHP script you can use `header()` to send/modify that information.

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: application/xml; charset: utf-8");
?>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
...
```

If you like to include the extension `.xml` in the URLs, you can use rewrite rules and/or change the web server configuration to execute `*.xml` files as PHP scripts. But that will not change how the web browser handles the response.